# Can I get store config value in layout xml file?

Tags: layout-update

In my extension I want to add custom link to the customer account page menu.
there is my xml layout update file

```
<customer_account>
    <reference name="customer_account_navigation">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="remarks"><name>remarks</name><path>remarks/remarks</path><label>Remarks</label></action>
    </reference>
</customer_account>

<remarks_remarks_index translate="label">
    <label>Remarks</label>
    <update handle="customer_account"/>
    <!--some content-->
</remarks_remarks_index>
```

So the problem is that value for link label is configured in system store config. How can I get it and pass to the `<label>` tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/catalog.xml in the line 63. There you can see

```
<action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="catalog" ifconfig="catalog/seo/site_map">
    <label>Site Map</label>
    <url helper="catalog/map/getCategoryUrl" />
    <title>Site Map</title>
</action>
```

Check the `<url helper="catalog/map/getCategoryUrl" />`
 in particular, you might find that useful. It is possible you can call a helper to retrieve the config you need and return it from there.