# How can add a block to layout, if there is a CMS Block exist in the layout?

Tags: layout, magento-1, event-observer, cms-block

So here is the situation. I need to create a `core/template` block programmatically, if there is `CMS Block`(`Static Block`) is present in layout structure. I will use this template to add some content to it dynamically.

If there is any observer for static blocks, I may use it. Another option would be, I can achieve the same through layouts, if there is static block specific layout handle is there (just like `cms_page` layout handle).

But I couldn't find any observer for static blocks yet. So I can't go with observer. I also look for any static block specific layout handle. That search also made me desperate. I couldn't find one. So the layout updation is also not possible.

So it seems to be the only way that I can achieve this is, to observe any general events(May be `controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_after`). But I feel it is too bad way..

So what should I do now ?  What would be the best method to do this? Can I need to create a custom event listener for static blocks (I don't know whether it is possible !!)? Share your thoughts.

**Note :** I am creating an extension. I want it as clean as possible. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that, there is no other way to do this. So I listened the general event `controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_after` . There I created new block if cms block present.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use a helper in the XML and check for a condition inside it, doing a conditional inside the XML and then act consequently. It might be better than observing each and every block load with an observer.

[Here is](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/23697/can-i-get-store-config-value-in-layout-xml-file/23702#23702) an answer for doing the XML approach.

```
<action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="catalog" ifconfig="catalog/seo/site_map">
    <label>Site Map</label>
    <url helper="catalog/map/getCategoryUrl" />
    <title>Site Map</title>
</action>
```

Comment: I dont think it would solve my problem. Reason is I wanto programmatically include a template.

Comment: This is an untested approach for layouts. You mentioned in your question you wanted to use layouts if possible and this is a way to connect a layout with some code. It is up to you to make it work, but with some logic it might actually work in a clean way.

Comment: Ok.. I will make a look on your suggestion. If it worked I will let you know. :)

Comment: I have a doubt. I think `ifconfig` points to system -> configuration section. But in my case, I am using syste config.

Comment: I dont understand the difference. Also the trick is in <url helper> and not in that ifconfig.